# Display a file by different users

Tags: media, users, files

I have a problem when i want to see a file uploaded.I created a `managed_file` like this :

```
$form['document']['footer_file'] = array(
    '#name' => 'footer_picture',
    '#title' => t('Footer file'),
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#description' => t('Put here a "PNG" picture.'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('footer_file'),
    '#upload_location' => 'private://mydoc/header-footer/',
    '#upload_validators' => array(
         'file_validate_extensions' => array('png'),
    ),
);
```

I log into my drupal website with a normal user, next i upload a file with the field created highter and the file is uploaded in the right folder. After that i go to my page where the picture is displayed and i can see her. Next i change my user and log with another user, when i go to the page where the picture is displayed i can't see her. when i inspect HTML code, there is the same link :

```
<img src="https://mydomain/system/files/mydoc/header-footer/image1.png">
```

When i click on this link with first user, i see the picture. And when i click on the link with second user, i'm redirected to `https://mydomain/user/login`

So, my question is : When i create programmatically a managed_file, there is permission on this file ? just the person who uploaded the file can see the picture ? Because i need to display the picture uploaded for all users.

Thanks

Comment: If you need it to be public, why are you saving it in the private file system?

Comment: Ok it's my fault, i don't know why i chose private for this case... thanks

Comment: since your problem is solved, please be sure to either close the question, or add an answer and then accept that answer so the question does not continue to be listed as unanswered